# How to pass laravel request data to java-script if validation failed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

laravel Controller

```
if($validator->failed())
{
    return redirect()->back()->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors(),'input'=>$request]);
}
```

JavaScript file

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
    var registrationErrors = @json($errors);
    var input= @json($input);
</script>
```

In this case registrationErrors  it's working fine but input return error like

`Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined.`

Comment: So only `@json($input)` is not working?

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Can you add an example of the $input object?

Comment: $input data is a $request->all(); object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pass only one argument in with() function that should be work fine.
Laravel Controller

```
if($validator->failed())
{
     $data=["errors"=>$validator->errors(),
            "input" => $input 
           ];
     return redirect()->back()->with('data',$data);
}
```

Java Script

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
     var data = @json($data);
</script>
```

My issue is solved, this way is perfectly working